# What is known about trailing data after the EOI marker (FFD9) in JPEG images?

Tags: image, io, format, jpeg

I recently wrote a JPEG parser (not a decoder), which I tested on a large image set. Out of curiosity, I continued reading the files after parsing the EOI marker. I was a bit surprised, how many files have trailing data.

In many cases, it seems to be some sort of padding (a sequence of 0x00 or 0xFF) and some Samsung cameras obviously store a JPEG thumbnail with size 640x480 after EOI (either directly afterwards or with a few zeros padding).

Other files were images I recovered from an accidentally deleted compact flash card, so I suppose the trailing data is some unneeded leftover from the recovery process (other images from the same camera have no trailing data).

However, there are other files that seem to have some hidden metadata. For example, I found an album cover image with the trailing string (without the quotes):

```
"8999m7gm000h.j31200204250410150300x0300  090                   "
```

`300x300` is the image size and `200204250410150` could be a timestamp.

Other images have HTML fragments after FFD9, like `" <font face="Arial" size=2>\n<p>"` in [this image of the Golden Gate Bridge](http://www.sanfrancisco.wz.cz/fotky/fotky/gg/gg136.jpg), which seems completely useless.

Corresponding google searches on the topic did not turn up much. Does anyone know anything about the deliberate or accidental use of trailing data in JPEG images?

Comment: Partly seems a too large buffer for the last bytes having been written in its entire length. Are those images a multiple of 128, 1024 or such?

Comment: That's something I didn't think of. The length of the album cover and the golden gate bridge however are not even multiples of 2. But that does not necessarily mean something, since the buffer bounds could have been changed by the encoding process.